# Puppeteer headless mode does not run properly

Tags: forms, puppeteer, headless

I'm using puppeteer to automatically submit a form online. It works perfectly fine in non-headless mode. But when using headless mode on puppeteer, the website does not process the submission and gives the following message.

[image]

Is there any way to get it to work on headless mode? I have tried using a random useragent with:

```
var result = random_useragent.getRandom();
await page.setUserAgent(result)
```

Also using the locally installed chrome for launching.

Comment: High chance the website is blocking headless browsers.

Answer (score 0):

We'd need more information about the site to provide a concrete answer, but your best bet is to try to mask the fact that your browser is headless. Here's a resource I found helpful: https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/.
Also, you can try using puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth: https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth. If that isn't the problem, you can try and set your [window size](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#window-size). Hope that works!

Comment: The site is https://www.deadstock.ca/pages/raffle. I tried plugin stealth and tried random user-agent with the code i posted in the question. These don't seem to do the trick. The error message comes after you hit the subscribe button in the form.